# SharePoint 2010 search results

Tags: search

Is there a way to setup a search page in SharePoint 2010 that only returns the sites that I have access to? Example, we have 100 team sites in our farm, I have access to 20 of them but I don't want to bookmark all of them.  I would like to have a search page where I type team into the search query box and return only the sites where I am a Owner, memeber or visitor.  We use the word "team" in the URL of our sites and have a Teams site collection for these sites.  Currently if I type "team" into the search box it returns anything within the farm that has the word team in it, all sites and documents.  I just want the site that I have access to.  Thanks.

Comment: Search results are already security trimmed... you should only see the sites you have access to?

Answer (score 1):

You can append ContentClass:STS_Site to the search query or add it to the Search Core Results Web part.

Answer (score 0):

Laura's article at http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=90
explains how to do this